# List of table names not getting displayed in pl/sql editor

Tags: oracle11g

I have created a table named USERCREDENTIAL. It's showing under the table heading, but whenever I write a query like

```
select * from USER
```

my table USERCREDENTIALS is not automatically displaying (this feature should come automatically).

I'm using Oracle 11g,PL/SQL editor.
Please help me out.

Comment: what data `USER` contain??? or you mean `ALL_USERS`???

Comment: Try `select * from USER_TABLES`

Comment: Table name is USERCREDENTIALS and not USER..I just want to say that my table name is not getting displayed automatically when I write few starting letters of the table name.